# Macro to auto fill text in a column down to the last cell in one table (while there are additional tables below)

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

[example of tables in the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBpr.png)

Hi I am new to VBA and wanted to create a macro that can auto fill column "Y/N" (as shown in the attached pic) with the text "Yes" by clicking a button.

Right now I have 3 rows in the first table, which is fine and I used the following code:

```
Sub autofill1()
Range("E12").Value = "Yes"
Range("E12").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E12:E14")
End Sub
```

However, the rows in the first table will keep changing, say it becomes 20, 50, 100 depending on different cases. I wonder if there's a way for me to define the auto fill range to be cell E12 to the last cell in this table, not to extend to the rest of the tables below.

I checked the codes provided for other similar questions - looks like it will auto fill all the way down to the last cell in my worksheet, which is the last cell in this column of the 5th table. And I don't want that. Is there a way to only auto fill down to the last cell of the 1st table? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: why don't you just do `Range("E12:E14")="Yes"` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, adding "yes" until found a bottom border.

```
Sub autofill1()
'Range("E12").Value = "Yes"
'Range("E12").Select
'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E12:E14")
Dim i As Long
i = 11
Do While Range("E" & i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle _
= xlNone
i = i + 1
Cells(i, 5) = "Yes"

Loop

End Sub
```